# How can I use the same layout multiple times on a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout

TL; DR: How can I use the same layout multiple times on a page? All attempts to render partials with recurring layouts go into the elements where the first time the layout is used.

Quick Info:

Using

```
Rails 2.3.14
Ruby 1.8.7
```

My partials  use content_for, which is pretty handy with layouts.

Basically, my layout looks like this:

```
<div class="header">
    <%= yield :modal_header %>
</div>
<div class="body">
    <%= yield :modal_body or yield %>
</div>
```

Generally, this is how I use my modal layout:

```
<% content_for :modal_header do %>
    header text / elements
<% end %>

<% content_for :modal_body do %>
    body info / settings for object or warning message, etc
<% end %>
```

This is how I render modals on my page:

```
<%= render :partial => "section_options", :layout => "modal" %>
```

and that works really well

BUT

when, on the same page, I try to render another modal:

```
<%= render :partial => "section_content_options", :layout => "modal" %>
```

This is what happens to the modal at the top of my page (occurs first in the HTML document)

```
<div class="header">
    -- header from second partial --
    -- header from first partial --
</div>
<div class="body">
    -- body from second partial --
    -- body from first partial --
</div>
```

and then later in the page, where the content from the second partial is supposed to be: 
everything is rendered correctly ... 
For the sake of this example:

```
<div class="header">
    section content options
</div>

<div class="body">
   section contents options ... options
   lil confirm / cancel buttons
</div>
```

Is there a way to fix this? This behavior really messes with javascript bindings as well. so. yup.

Is there a bug with layouts in rails 2.3.14? do I have to upgrade to rails 3 to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modals should be rendered using partials, not layouts. Layouts are designed as a way of defining the overall layout of the *entire* site, not specific parts. Something like a modal (which by design is specific) should be a partial that's rendered either through a condition or JavaScript.

Comment: can partials have things placed in certain places like yield does in a layout?

Comment: A partial can have any HTML/ERB inside it, just like a layout. The difference is that the partial represents a 'partial' section of a layout. It's typically used to extract/refactor complex pieces of layout into individual parts, like for instance a modal dialog. This also means that you can re-use the partial as many times as you like within the layout or an individual view.

Comment: I know that. But that's not waht I'm asking about, I don't think.  With layouts, you can define a bunch of markup that would otherwise be used often in one place. Then, when you want to render anything, you can define what would go in the placeholders in that layout. Is this possible with partials?

Comment: That's exactly what partials were designed for, yes. I personally render modal dialogs as partials in the layout file unless they're specific to a view.

Comment: So, you never have more than one modal rendered (yet hidden) at once? are there any design ... smells? (i guess), about creating my own partial / layout hybrid? so I can have the functionality I want?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You can render as many modals as you like, as long as you render them properly (usually through Javascript I guess?). The key reason this works is simply because rendering a partial just prints the HTML of the partial inside the layout when the layout is rendered. Therefore you can render a partial that has a generic layout for a modal, and then pass parameters to it through Javascript to define its content/header etc. This is how I do it at least and it's quite effective (and also very DRY).